# How is the parent component constructor getting called when child component event is triggered

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-components

I'm following [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service). I could grasp the concepts in this tutorial context except one.
When confirm button is clicked, the `confirm()` event is raised.

```
confirm() {
this.confirmed = true;
this.missionService.confirmMission(this.astronaut);
}
```

Here I understood that using `missionService`, the `astronaut` is added to the subject. Hence to retrieve it the following code is obvious.

```
constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
missionService.missionConfirmed$.subscribe(
  astronaut => {
    this.history.push(`${astronaut} confirmed the mission`);
  });
}
```

But I'm unable to comprehend as to why it has been coded inside the constructor of the parent and does the constructor gets called every time the event is raised?

To my knowledge, I thing constructors get called only at the component tree construction. Hence I'm unable to follow up the sequences of the flow of control.
Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand this example, you should first understand how the Observables work.

In nutshell, the observables are an implementation of the observer design pattern which has two actors. The **subject** and the **observers**. A subject can have more than one observers. In order, someone to become an observer, should **subscribe** to a **subject**.

In your example, the **missionConfirmed$** is the subject and the **observer** is the code:

```
astronaut => {
      this.history.push(`${astronaut} confirmed the mission`);
}
```

The observer gets invoked every time the subject emits a message.
As you said, the constructor is invoked only once during the class construction. However, the part inside the constructor (the observer) is invoked whenever the `this.missionService.confirmMission(this.astronaut);` emits a message

Comment: Yes today I had a walk through on observables and I understood it perfect with you explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the constructor of the parent it is "subscribing" to the observable (`missionConfirmed$`) of the service (`missionService`). The "subscribing" part is done once, but the code executed when a value is passed onto that observable by doing `missionConfirmed$.next(newAstronaut)` is execute each time a new `next()` is called.

So for each `next(newAstronaut)` a new astronaut comes in at

```js
  astronaut => { //<-- this will be the new astronaut
    this.history.push(`${astronaut} confirmed the mission`);
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean that since a new astronaut ` new instance ` is created, the constructor of the parent is called each time?

Comment: The constructor of the parent is not called each time. Its the function `astronaut => { this.history.push('${astronaut} confirmed the mission');` that will be called each time the service does `this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);`

Answer (score 0):

No, the constructor is not called. It's the observer inside of it that is called.

```
constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
  missionService.missionConfirmed$.subscribe(
    // This will be called on each next()
    astronaut => {
      this.history.push(`${astronaut} confirmed the mission`);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more elaborative?

Comment: If you put a `console.log()` right after the constructor, you'll see that it gets called only once when the component is initialized. If you put another `console.log()` inside the `astronaut => { ... } ` function you'll see that it gets called every time `this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);` is called.

Comment: I modified the live demo a bit. Here's what I meant. Take a look at the messages in the console. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtznz3?file=src/app/missioncontrol.component.ts